# How to set default value for select-option angular

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, formgroups

I want to set a default value for select option 'John' in ngOninit ( When page loads). I am not sure If I am using the select option correctly. Please correct me If I am wrong.

I trying to set value using form group and form control. But I am not able to set default value when page loads.

Here is the stackblitz link where I am trying to set default value as 'John' when page loads but it is blank. Please correct me If I am wrong anywhere, thanks

Link: [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-s1671t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) event runs before the `FormControl` is connected to the `select` in the template that is why it does not get updated. Call the set value in the [AfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) event when everything is already initialized so the `select` will get the value form the `FormControl`.

Here is a [link to a fork of your StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-anorif?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) that demonstrates it.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work without `value` in options:

```html
<option *ngFor="let name of names" [value]="name">{{name}}</option>
```